# A mapping that maps circles centered at origin to lines parallel the real axis

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

I need a mapping that maps a circle (with the center at the origin) to lines parallel to real axis:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well converting to polar coordinates would be the obvious choice: $$T(x,y)=\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\arctan\left({y\over x}\right)\right)$$ Then $$T(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))=(1,\theta)$$ which is a vertical line. You could adjust accordingly if you needed it to be that horizontal line.

Comment: Isn't $\log z$ simpler? I think it can do the job. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes that works.